# Android TextView Left Gravity Problem in an Item XML for RecyclerView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, android-constraintlayout

I have an RecyclerViewAdapter and I'm preparing an item xml to display my all items as list.

I've written my xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutAutoCompleteTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_film_add_recycler_view">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewFilmName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/figma_text_color_dark"
        android:fontFamily="@font/inter500_regular"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageViewFilmLogo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageViewFilmLogo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageViewFilmLogo"
        tools:text="MyFilm">
    </TextView>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewFilmLogo"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
    </ImageView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

As result of this, I see my RecyclerView like this (red ones are textviews, green ones are imageviews):

[image]

As you see, the textviews looks like centered in specific area. But I want aligned to left like this:

[image]

I tried to add `android:gravity="left"` but it doesn't work, what is the problem? can you help me please?

If possible, can you equilaze the distances between "left edge of layout - imageview" and "imageview - left edge of textview"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutAutoCompleteTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_film_add_recycler_view">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewFilmLogo"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription">
    </ImageView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textViewFilmName_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageViewFilmLogo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageViewFilmLogo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageViewFilmLogo"
        android:paddingStart="30dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewFilmName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/figma_text_color_dark"
            android:fontFamily="@font/inter500_regular"
            tools:text="MyFilm">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `0dp` for views if you wish to set behavior of view like `layout_gravity="start"` in constraintLayout
And don't forget add margin start for second element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutAutoCompleteTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_film_add_recycler_view">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewFilmName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/figma_text_color_dark"
        android:fontFamily="@font/inter500_regular"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageViewFilmLogo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageViewFilmLogo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageViewFilmLogo"
        tools:text="MyFilm">
    </TextView>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewFilmLogo"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
    </ImageView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for answer but the previous answer has additionally solution for distancing, but I give you upvote